# "D.I. Mendeleyev Institute for Metrology" vs. "D.I. Mendeleyev Institute of Metrology"

Tags: prepositions

On the official English-language [website of the institute](http://vniim.ru/index.en.html), it is called thus:

> D.I. Mendeleyev Institute **for** Metrology

However, I find this a bit jarring. I would use **of**:

> D.I. Mendeleyev Institute **of** Metrology

Is this **for** acceptable in this case - since I do find some instances of "[institute for](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&newwindow=1&hl=ru&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%22institute%20for%22&oq=%22institute%20for%22)" online? Or is it better to consider this a minor mistake by the website's creators (who are not native speakers of English) and to change it to **of** in my translation?

The instances with **for** that I find seem to carry a sense that is different from my case. There, **for** seems to convey the sense of "in support of":

> Institute for Diversity
>   Institute for Sustainability

The D.I. Mendeleyev Institute must be simply a place "where metrology is being taught and studied", and not a place "where metrology is being supported or promoted", thus I'd pick **of**.

Comment: Even a metrologist would have a hard time measuring the difference between the two. Both are acceptable.  **for** = purpose,  E,g, compare the English names of the various Max Planck institutes for ...., or the Princeton Institute for the Science and Technology of Materials.

Comment: Using "for" in English is fine, if you think of it as "D.I. Mendeleyev Institute for (the benefit/study/understanding of) Metrology". Any translation issue is another matter.

Comment: Because it's a name, I would not change it in my translation. It's their name and they may call themselves however they want. Meanwhile, I do agree, I would use "of" myself, for the same reason that you state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *Metrology* within the title *D.I. Mendeleyev Institute for Metrology* is best thought of as meaning *the  study of measurement* or *the study of metrology*.

So the preposition *for* within the phrase *for Metrology* is perfectly apt here. It means *for the benefit of and promotion of the study of measurement*. This would bring the title of this institute in line with other institutes such as:

- The Institute for Materials and Processes
- The Institute for Digital Communications
- The Institute for Employment Studies

and many others as well.

Although *Institute of...* is more common, many very prestigious insitutes quite properly use *Institute for...* instead.

Comment: It still feels like the use of **for** is more "pretentious". "The Institute for Materials and Processes" - good find! Clearly a phrase coined by native speakers. But feels not very apt.. I'll just memorize that this usage is okay.